# why does 'netsh wlan show profiles' return non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I read how to fix this error on the Internet and tried to figure it out myself, but it didn't work out, can you please help

```
import subprocess


def extract_wifi_password():
    profiles_data = subprocess.check_output('netsh wlan show profiles').decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    profiles = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in profiles_data if 'All User Profile' in i]

    for profile in profiles:
        profile_info = subprocess.check_output(f'netsh wlan show profile {profile} key=clear').decode('utf-8').split('\n')
        try:
            password = [i.split(':')[1].strip() for i in profile_info if 'Key Content' in i][0]
        except IndexError:
            password = None

        with open(file='wifi_password.ixi', mode='a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
            file.write(f'Profiles: {profile}\nPassword: {password}\n{"#" * 20}\n')
```

and return `subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'netsh wlan show profiles' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: This can't be your whole code, because `extract_wifi_password()` is never called. Please make a [mre] then [edit] it into the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: `netsh` has to be run elevated.  Are you in an administrator shell?

Answer (score 0):

> Hi I have solved all the errors and code to find all the wifi passwords is :

```
import subprocess

class Main():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.allWifiNames = []
        self.wifiNames = []
        self.paswords = []
        self.wifiNamesWithPasword = {}
        self.NoOFPasswordNotFound = 0

        self.meta_data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles'])
        # decoding meta data
        self.data = self.meta_data.decode('utf-8', errors ="backslashreplace")
        # splitting data by line by line
        self.data = self.data.split('\n')

        self.profileGetter()
        self.passwordGetter()
        # print(self.wifiNamesWithPasword)

        if self.NoOFPasswordNotFound==0:
            print("Sir, I have sucessfully found passwords for all wifi networks")
        else:
            found = len(list(self.wifiNamesWithPasword.keys()))
            notFound = self.NoOFPasswordNotFound
            print(f"Sir, I have found passwords of {found} networks out of {found+notFound}  ")


    def profileGetter(self):
        newL = []
        # Getting all the names of wifi
        for i in self.data:
            if "All User Profile" in i:
                newL.append(i)
        # Stripping whitspaces and unnecessary things from names
        for p in newL:
            name = ""
            startAppending = False
            for q in p:
                if startAppending:
                    name+=str(q)
                if q==":":
                    startAppending = True
                if q=="\\":
                    startAppending = False
            self.allWifiNames.append(name)
        self.wifiNames = []
        for name in self.allWifiNames:
            name = name.rstrip()
            newName = name.replace(" ","",1)
            self.wifiNames.append(newName)

    
    def passwordGetter(self):
        for i in self.wifiNames:
            try :
                # Getting password of all wifi networks
                wifiName = i
                print('Trying to get password for = "{0}"'.format(i))
                meta_data_password = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile',f"{wifiName}",'key=clear'])
                meta_data_password = meta_data_password.decode("UTF-8")
                meta_data_password = meta_data_password.split("\n")

                # Checking if the wifi is open or it has password
                isWifiOpen = None
                for i in meta_data_password:
                    if "Authentication" in i:
                        if "Open" in i:
                            isWifiOpen = True
                        else:
                            isWifiOpen = False

                # Stripping whitspaces and unnecessary things from password
                password = ""
                if not isWifiOpen:
                    for p in meta_data_password:
                        if "Key Content" in p:
                            name = ""
                            startAppending = False
                            for q in p:
                                if startAppending:
                                    name+=str(q)
                                if q=="\\":
                                    startAppending = False
                                if q==":":
                                    startAppending = True
                            password=name
                    password = password.rstrip()
                    password = password.replace(" ","")
                else:
                    password = "WIFI IS OPEN"
                self.wifiNamesWithPasword[wifiName] = password

            # Handling any error if it arises
            except Exception as e:
                self.NoOFPasswordNotFound+=1


a = Main()
# print(a.NoOFPasswordNotFound)
print(a.wifiNamesWithPasword)
```

Comment: If you face any error in this code or if you have a better way of doing this, please mail me on "dhamejanishivam@gmail.com"

Answer (score -1):

You are not passing the arguments to `subprocess.check_output` correctly. You either need to pass `shell=True`, or you should pass a list or tuple of strings (e.g. `['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile']`) instead of one long string.

The error you're getting is because there is no single command `'netsh wlan show profiles'`. The program you want to run is `netsh` and the rest of the line is arguments to that command.

Comment: ok, I did what you wrote and realized my mistake, but nothing changed as a result

Comment: This doesn't resolve the problem. I still get the error.